# How can I define callback function for an option in Owl Carousel 2?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

I am trying to change value of an option by coming value from database. In order to do this, I think i should define a callback function. But it's not working.

My callback function is:

```
function nav_cb(){
    if( settings.nav==='on' ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And my init codes are here.

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    nav: nav_cb,
    dots: true,
});
```

But it doesn't accept this result of function. How can i make it return true or false?

Comment: The option `nav` accepts a Boolean not a callback: `nav: nav_cb()`....

Answer (score 0):

I've just found it myself. They should be like this. Working fine.

```
var nav_check = 0;
if( settings.nav==='on' ){
    nav_check = true;
}else{
    nav_check = false;
}


var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    nav: nav_check,
    dots: true,
});
```